# Start an Azure WebJobs from Javascript code

Tags: javascript, azure, automation, node-modules, azure-webjobs

Is there any node package or something else to start (Run) an Azure Webjob from JS? I'm an automation guy and I want to start an Azure Webjob to change some statuses in the app. Manually I just press "Run", but I want to start the job using code. An option is to login in UI and press the run button using automation, but is not looking professional for me to do it from UI.

I saw some infos there, in Webjob properties like webhook, user, password. Maybe I can use somehow those things to trigger using code.

Thank you!

Comment: I would consider giving a look at Azure Functions which will let you trigger things from anywhere you want, including your JavaScript app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to manage Azure WebJob with node, we can use the package [`azure-arm-website`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-arm-website/v/5.7.0). The package provides the method `runTriggeredWebJobWithHttpOperationResponse` to run a trigger WebJob and the method `startContinuousWebJobWithHttpOperationResponse` to continuous WebJob.

For example

1. Create a service pricipal

```
az login
az account set --subscription "SUBSCRIPTION_ID"
az ad sp create-for-rbac --role "Contributor" --scopes "/subscriptions/<subscription_id>"
```

2. Code

```
const {
  ApplicationTokenCredentials,
  AzureEnvironment,
} = require("ms-rest-azure");
const { WebSiteManagementClient } = require("azure-arm-website");

const clientId = "<the sp appId>";
const tenant = "<you AD tenant domain>";
const clientSecret = "<the sp password>";
const subscriptionId = "";
const creds = new ApplicationTokenCredentials(clientId, tenant, clientSecret, {
  environment: AzureEnvironment.Azure,
});

const client = new WebSiteManagementClient(creds, subscriptionId);
const rgName = "rg-webapp-demo";
const webName = "demo-200925164220";

const jobName = "test";
client.webApps
  .runTriggeredWebJobWithHttpOperationResponse(rgName, webName, jobName)
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res.response.statusMessage);
    console.log(res.response.statusCode);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    throw err;
  });

  client.webApps.startContinuousWebJob
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hey! Thank for the comprehensive answer! Do you have any hint where I can get the "clientId", "tenant", "clientSecret" and "rgname"? in portal, for the jobs properties I have only web hook, username and password. Thank you in advance! I'm not familiar with Azure, that's why I'm asking these things. Thank you and I appreciate the help!

Comment: @icsul When we run the step one, we will create service principal and assign role to it. After doing that, we get `clientId` etc. Besides, the web job host in azure web app. So we need to the resource group name and web app name befor managing web job.

Comment: @icsul Do you have any other concerns? If you have no other concerns, could you please accept it as an answer?